# Saving Arduino sensor data to text file

Tags: arduino, text-files, sensors

I've been working to save data from an accelerometer sensor to a text file. But after searching the web for several hours, the methods I've found haven't worked. Here is the program I have now.

```
// Accelerometer sensor program

const int ar1 = A5; 
const int ar2 = A4;
const int ar3 = A3;

int x = 0;        
int ov1 = 0;    
int y = 0;      
int ov2= 0;      
int z = 0;       
int ov3= 0;      

void setup() {
  // initialize the communications
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  analogReference(EXTERNAL);    //connect 3.3v to AREF

  // X axis
  // Read the analog
  x = analogRead(ar1);            
  // Range of analog out
  ov1 = map(x, 0, 1023, 0, 255);  
  delay(2);                     

  // Y axis
  y = analogRead(ar2);            
  ov2 = map(y, 0, 1023, 0, 255); 

 // Z axis 
  delay(2);                 
  z = analogRead(ar3);            
  ov3 = map(z, 0, 1023, 0, 255);  

// Should print to the monitor
// Output for X axis
  Serial.print("Xsensor1 = " );                       
  Serial.print(x);      
  Serial.print("\t output1 = ");      
  Serial.println(ov1);   

// Output for Y axis
  Serial.print("Ysensor2 = " );                       
  Serial.print(y);      
  Serial.print("\t output2 = ");      
  Serial.println(ov2);   

// Output for Z axis
  Serial.print("Zsensor3 = " );                       
  Serial.print(z);      
  Serial.print("\t output3 = ");      
  Serial.println(ov3);   

// Should repeat every second
  delay(1000);
```

What I've found does seem to do what I want, the issue is that Arduino doesn't want to run it, saying that 'import' was not declared in the scope. I've tried installing some libraries, but I couldn't find the exact library that import is part of, or PrintWriter for that matter. Here is the code causing issues:

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial mySerial;
PrintWriter output;
void setup() {
   mySerial = new Serial( this, Serial.list()[0], 9600 );
   output = createWriter( "data.txt" );
}
void draw() {
    if (mySerial.available() > 0 ) {
         String value = mySerial.readString();
         if ( value != null ) {
              output.println( value );
         }
    }
}

void keyPressed() {
    output.flush();  // Writes the remaining data to the file
    output.close();  // Finishes the file
    exit();  // Stops the program
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have isn't for the Arduino but is written in a language called Processing. It will run on your PC and collect the data from the Arduino to be saved to a file. You need to download the [Processing IDE](https://processing.org/download/) to compile the code and run it.